# 'Git GC' command deleted all files in 'objects' folder, yet I can access the objects from Git bash

Tags: bash, git, gitlab

I have created a brand new folder and ran these commands

```
> git init
> touch one.txt
> git add one.txt
> git commit -m "First commit"
> git gc
```

Now interestingly I don't see any of the object folders inside .git/objects folder (Except the default info and pack folders), which were present prior to running 'git gc' command.

But I could still read all the objects (Blog, Tree, Commit objects) from git bash using 'git cat-file' command. For example I could run these..

```
> git cat-file -p 5be1e55ad5a
```

here "5be1e55ad5a" is the commit ID I got form 'git log' command.

Now I have two questions.

1. What is the intent of 'git gc' command when it deleted all the object folders form 'objects' directory
2. How am I able to still access the objects form git bash? Where is git getting them from?

Thanks you!

Comment: Git init configures a local repository on your machine, and you committed a file into it.  So of course you can view it, it is still in there.  `git gc`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc.  It does not delete anything or render files inaccessible.  It does some "spring cleaning" of internal git files, but does nothing to your repository from a file content view point.

Answer (score 2):

All your loose objects are now stored in pack files to save disk space.

See this documentation for more details: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles